# Unexpected behaviour when summarizing a field in ArcMap (Un-Equal strings)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, encoding, arabic

I couldn't figure out why when I use summarize the Field " LandUse_Arabic " it the summary shows two identical values in the output table.

[image]

[image]

But when I use select by attribute, despite the fact that ArcMAP 10.2.2 displays the 2 values It selects all values which are 47

[image]
[image]

What might be the issue here ?

Comment: Hard to guess, but have you tried copying the values into Notepad to check if there are any trailing spaces?

Comment: Many thanks Alex, I have tried this and I could confirm that they are identical " empty of spaces "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the encoding of the characters for these two words are different. for example, for the character ی , we have two unicode, one for persian (ی) and one for arabic (ي). The visual difference is the two dots under the arabic version. these two characters appear exactly the same when inserted in the middle of a word (حدیقه or حديقه) but they are not equal.

I don't understand this behavior of Arcmap but maybe the select by attribute tool is ignoring characters ascii or unicodes. if the source table if from a shape file consider checking the codepage of shapefile encoding.

However to solve the problem, select all 47 records and use the field calculator to set them to a typed version of your word.

I hope it helps

Comment: Many thanks Farid, But as you see I have a massive FC with 38000 records, and the problem isn't only with "حدیقه" I have more than one value, the question now  is How to force the FC to use  only Arabic Unicode and ignore the Persian.

Comment: You cannot force the FC to do so. Except shapefiles, feature classes inside the geodatabase, are unicode meaning they accept any character in any language. it is your or your users responsibility to input the right set of characters (here arabic characters). To do so one should set the proper input keyboard in the Operating System.

Comment: To solve the problem with all of your records I recommend to use Find&Replace... tool of Attribute Table to replace all persian ی to that of arabic ي  . I suppose this will solve your problem

Comment: Many thanks Farid, I think I will use the long way using the field calculator, by the way I am using FME to generate the land use and the users Do not enter values in ArcMAP since I am linking an excel with the autocad files then using FME workbench to genreate the FC.